# How to upgrade Magento 2.1.4 to Magento 2.4.3 latest version

Tags: upgrade, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.3

Hi here my site is running on Magento 2.1.4 and I m having a complete site with many products on the store, Is it possible to Upgrade my Magento to 2.4.3 without affecting the Modules or Products.
How can achieve it, can I get some Help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. at first always backup your site.
2. check Magento system requirements https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html and match them with your current server environment. (remember that magento>2.3.* needs an elasticsearch)
3. check if you have a third-party extension and see if they support Magento latest version.
4. do the upgrade

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 --no-update
composer update
```

*after the upgrade, at some point it may affect your site if you have a lot of custom modules with preference or if you have a custom theme, you have to check all pages and functionalities and see if they are still working well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, After Upgrade Product display page and product listing pages are throwing errors.